# How to debug headless Electron preload script failure?

Tags: debugging, electron, headless

I have an Electron app with code like

```
let win = new BrowserWindow({ show: false, frame: false, webPreferences: {preload: "/path/to/preload.js", ...}, ...});
```

and while developing new feature, I missed one closing parenthesis and one closing brace. Of course, I didn't know that and I instead got output to console while trying to launch the app

```
[18330:1204/142153.915989:INFO:CONSOLE(91)] "Unable to load preload script: /path/to/preload.js", source: electron/js2c/renderer_init.js (91)
[18330:1204/142153.916049:INFO:CONSOLE(91)] "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list", source: electron/js2c/renderer_init.js (91)
```

For some reason, electron doesn't want to share the exception it actually receives while trying to load the preload script. For example, line number of the original parse error would be great! So I end up with no clue about the real cause barely on the log alone. Note that this issue is about problems with preload script contents - I know that some people are having problems with the preload script not being found by electron.

Also note that the second line in the log claims that error is on file `electron/js2c/renderer_init.js` on line 91 which is obviously only incorrect reporting from electron.

**Is there a way to get the actual parse error to log?** I'm trying to create headless app to be run with `xvfb-run` so I need to have output in the log.

I'm currently working with electron v10.0.1 but I'm willing to take hints for any version. Currently the only way forward is to use external linters or randomly comment out newly modified code blocks and try to figure out the problem manually. There must be a better way.

I'm already passing following command line flags to electron:

```
--enable-logging --v=2 --debug-print --noerrdialogs --headless
```